# why I get error when using int() function to convert float to integer?

Tags: python

Why do I get an error When I tried to use int() function to convert a float to integer?

```
>>> int('99.99')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#27>", line 1, in <module>
    int('99.99')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '99.99'
```

I expected the result to be 99

Comment: You're not converting a float, you're converting a string.

Comment: You aren't converting a float to an int; you are trying to convert a string containing a float literal. In the spirt of "explicit is better than implicit", `int` won't try to go from string to float to int implicitly. If you want to do this, be explicit: `int(float('99.99'))`.

Comment: This should get you what you want int(float('99.99'))

Comment: You are converting from string to int, it is failing because python doesn't expect an int to have a dot in it. Try `round(float('99.99))`. Maybe look at `Math.floor/ceil` depending on how you want it to round your number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument isn't a float, it's a string containing the representation of a float. You have to convert it to a float first, then you can convert that to an int.

```
int(float('99.99'))
```

Comment: Thanks, why can I get 100 using:   int('100')

Comment: Because `100` is an integer.

Comment: `int()` will convert a string to an integer if it contains the representation of an integer. If there are digits after the decimal point, it's not a valid integer.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#int)

> Return an integer object constructed from a number or string x, or
>   return 0 if no arguments are given. If x is a number, return
>   x.**int**(). For floating point numbers, this truncates towards zero.
>
> If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string,
>   bytes, or bytearray instance representing an integer literal in radix
>   base.

Pay particular attention to *"representing an integer literal"*. So your `str` that you are attempting to convert cannot be a float, because that's a float literal, not an int literal.

So, as others have noted, you cannot go directly from a float literal to an `int`, you need to convert the `float` first:

```py
x = '123.45'

int(float(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a `ValueError` because you are overloading `int()` with an argument that is not consistent with the Python docs.

According to the doc:

> "If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string or
>   Unicode object representing an integer literal "

Basically, x (in your case '99.99') is the string 99.99 which does not satisfy the requirements of being an integer literal. You provided a floating literal.

TL;DR

```
int(float('99.99'))
```