# Why can't I convert a float value enclosed within quotation marks to an int datatype in Python?

Tags: python

can anyone explain why a ValueError occurs when I try to convert a float datatype enclosed within quotation marks to an integer datatype?

Example of when ValueError occurs:

`print(int("7.3"))`

However, when I try to convert a value such as:

`print(int(7.3))`

No error occurs when trying to convert 7.3 not enclosed within quotation marks to an integer datatype

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why I get error when using int() function to convert float to integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56695588/why-i-get-error-when-using-int-function-to-convert-float-to-integer)

Answer (score 2):

**Because the string `"7.3"` can't be parsed as an integer (due to the decimal dot).** `int` tries to "cast" the value it gets to integer. For floats, this means flooring them; for strings, this means parsing them as ints. The string you are providing can't be parsed as an int because it is a textual float representation. For float parsing, use `float`:

`ìnt(float("7.3"))` will first parse `"7.3"` as the float `7.3` which will then be floored to `7` by `int`.

Comment: Can I clarify what you mean by "For floats, this means flooring them"? What exactly does flooring them mean? Thanks!

Comment: @bubbles `int(1.99999)` is `1`, just like `int(1.0000001)` is `1`. It basically cuts off all digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

From python docs

> Convert a number or string to an integer, or return 0 if no arguments
> are given.  If x is a number, return x.**int**().  For floating point
> numbers, this truncates towards zero.

> If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string,
> bytes, or bytearray instance **representing an integer** literal in the
> given base.

But what you are providing is a string which is representing a float literal instead of an integer literal.

To parse a string representing float to integer, this should work:

```py
int(float("7.3"))
```